# Javascript returns NaN

Tags: javascript

I have a function which does some maths on two numbers but i seem to get NaN as a return for it....  I don't know why though..... this is my function:

```
function mouseConvert(mousex,mousey){

 console.log(mousex+ ' '+ mousey);

    var x = (mousex + Data.offset_x) - (settings.width/2) - settings.offset_left;
    var y = (mousey + Data.offset_y) - settings.offset_top;
    var tx = Math.round((x + y * 2) / settings.grid) - 1;
    var ty = Math.round((y * 2 - x) / settings.grid) - 1;

 console.log(tx+ ' '+ ty);

return [tx,ty];
}
```

The console log output from the function shows:

[image]

Here is the value for `Data` and `settings`

[image]

Why is it not returning numbers but rather NaN ?

Comment: Using a debugger you can know what are the values of all the variables where the calculus is done.

Comment: You mean console.log ? I added a second picture showing the input values.... and the result.

Comment: Show me the logging code for the second statement

Comment: What do you mean "logging code"?

Comment: should log each statement you are making.  why wait till the end?

Comment: No. I mean : put a breakpoint and look at the [debugger](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts). Nobody should code without a debugger.

Comment: console.log("x is => " + x ), etc

Comment: Try logging `JSON.stringify(Data)` right before using the properties. The Chrome debugger evaluates the object when expanding it, so it may not be actual.

Comment: @Dave I mean the line with the `console.log` that produces the `NaN NaN` log (and the code after that; as noted by pimvdb, the values could change before being captured by the log)

Comment: Ok i checked the debugger the only unsual thing i saw was mousex and mousey are "0" and "0" instead of 0 and 0 ... could that mean they are not seen as numbers but rather seen as strings?

Comment: Yes. You need to convert mousex and mousey to numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if the mouse positions are strings like `"0"`, consider:

```
(mousex + Data.offset_x)
```

Becomes

```
"0" + -32 //"0-32"
```

The string `"0-32"` will then attempted to be converted to a number when you do subtraction with `- (settings.width/2)`. And `Number("0-32")` is `NaN`, after which everything becomes `NaN`.

You should convert them to a number right at the beginning. Or rather, never convert them to strings in the first place, since the event object has them as numbers already...

Answer (score 0):

U have to convert mouseX and mouseY to int or float parseInt or parseFloat

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var Data = { ipos: NaN, jpos: NaN, level: "1", money: "1000", offset_x: -32, offset_y: -250};
var settings = { grid: 64, height: 500, offset_left: 258, offset_top: 85, width: 1165};

function mouseConvert(mousex,mousey){
 mousex = parseInt(mousex);
 mousey = parseInt(mousey); 
console.log(mousex+ ' '+ mousey);

    var x = (mousex + Data.offset_x) - (settings.width/2) - settings.offset_left;
    var y = (mousey + Data.offset_y) - settings.offset_top;
    var tx = Math.round((x + y * 2) / settings.grid) - 1;
    var ty = Math.round((y * 2 - x) / settings.grid) - 1;

 console.log(tx+ ' '+ ty);

return [tx,ty];
}
mouseConvert('0', 1);
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

return

```
0 1 
-25 2
```

without parseInt it will return **Nan**

Comment: Can a mouse position be a float? or does it snap to integer location ?

Comment: mouse position will always be an int. There is no subpixel mouse positions.

Comment: but if you put 
   mousex = parseInt(mousex);
   mousey = parseInt(mousey);
the code is working