# jquery sorting not working in firefox and working in chrome and IE

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="container" data-price="30.00">30.00</div>
<div id="container" data-price="62.00">62.00</div>
<div id="container" data-price="12.00">12.00</div>
<div id="container" data-price="45.00">45.00</div>
<div id="container" data-price="28.00">28.00</div>
```

```
function sorterDesc(a, b) {
    return b.getAttribute('data-price') - a.getAttribute('data-price');
};

var sortedDivs = $('#container').toArray().sort(sorterDesc);
$.each(sortedDivs, function(index, value) {
    $('#container').append(value);
});
```

The above sorting is working in chrome and IE but not working in firefox. what was wrong in this code?

Comment: `.getAttribute('data-price')` returns string. You need to parse it to integer first.

Comment: Did you try in your sorting function to cast the data as float ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript returns NaN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771002/javascript-returns-nan)

Comment: I tried your code in FF, and got an error HierarchyRequestError. You might wanna check this out [HierarchyRequestError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256394/what-exactly-can-cause-an-hierarchy-request-err-dom-exception-3-error)

Comment: No, i didnt cast the data

Comment: one more thing, id should be unique . so you might wanna consider putting **.container** as a class and not as an ID :)

Comment: i used class only . for example i have given id

Comment: hi jamie, before return value i want to covert string to integer ?

Comment: I tried to change those Id to class and put them into a **div#container** and it works well in chrome/ff/ie. [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ooym87ga/). check it

Comment: i tried to convert float and int but not working

Answer (score 0):

this code now run in all browser.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" data-price="30.00">30.00</div>
    <div id="container" data-price="62.00">62.00</div>
    <div id="container" data-price="12.00">12.00</div>
    <div id="container" data-price="45.00">45.00</div>
    <div id="container" data-price="28.00">28.00</div>
    <div id="sortedDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function sorterDesc(a, b) {
        return b.getAttribute('data-price') - a.getAttribute('data-price');
    };

    var sortedDivs = $('[id*=container]').toArray().sort(sorterDesc);
    $.each(sortedDivs, function (index, value) {
        $('#sortedDiv').append(value);
    });
</script>
```